# UK family visit visa refused for Indian citizen mother-in-law

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, visa-refusals

I have applied for a visit visa for my mother-in-law to spend spending the Christmas holidays with us. However, it was rejected. In filling out the application, there are two columns, one for how much the applicant is willing to spend on the visit, and the other for much the sponsor will spend. I think I made a mistake and put in £3,000 for the first and £5,000 for the second. Can I correct my mistake and reapply?

From the rejection notice:

> **VISA APPLIED: CHENNAI, INDIA**
>   **VISA FOR : UK- VISIT VISA (FAMILY VISIT)**
>
> On your visa application form you state that you are unemployed with no income stated. You state that the cost to you personally of your trip is 3000£, you state that the total amount you spent each month is 50£. You have submitted a copy of STATE BANK OF INDIA account showing a balance of INR 118444 (1437 £) as at 13-10-2016, therefore the balance is less than you state that you have available.
>
> **Refusal reason**:
>
> Therefore I am not satisfied that your purpose in the UK is as you have stated and on the balance of probabilities I am not satisfied that you intend to leave the UK at the end of your visit as stated by you - and do not intend to live for extended periods in United Kingdom through frequent or successive visits or that you genuinely seeking entry as a visitor for a period not exceeding 6 months. Furthermore I am not satisfied you will have sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to your visit without working or accessing public funds V4.2 (a-e)
>
> **Future Applications**:
>
> Any future UK visa applications you make will be considered on their individual merits, however you are likely to be refused unless the circumstances of your application change.

Comment: Sure you can re-apply right away. But the ECO will see their history. For more details about bank statements, see the linked Q&A.